# IOS7 ignoring view port meta

Tags: ios7, viewport, retina-display

I'm having a real hard time trying to trouble shoot this issue.  I've seen others with the same problems but all seemed to find a fix, none of which work for my clients site.  I've tried a number of different combinations but nothing works.

The site is completely responsive on desktop, android, and IOS6 / below, but after the release of IOS7 it no longer displays correctly on any of the IOS7 browsers and defaults to the desktop layout (although fits all on the screen, still not ideal).  It's like it's ignoring the viewport settings for retina.

The website in question is www.grupoevents.com

I really appreciate any help as I've already spent hours trying to fix it!

This is probably the 6th variation of viewport I have tried now, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

What combinations have you used? I have used this in the past and it works for me.

```
<!-- standard viewport tag to set the viewport to the device's width, Android 2.3 devices need this so 100% width works properly and doesn't allow children to blow up the viewport width-->
<meta name="viewport" id="vp" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">

<!-- width=device-width causes the iPhone 5 to letterbox the app, so we want to exclude it for iPhone 5 to allow full screen apps -->
<meta name="viewport" id="vp" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1" media="(device-height: 568px)">
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. I was using:

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />

It scales the entire site to fit within the iPhone screen, but it essentially "zooms out" to display the entire website like it would on a desktop rather.  Like it ignores the meta tag which should tell a retina device to treat every 2 pixels like 1 pixel.

Comment: In the simulator I am seeing 2 meta tags with the name of viewport, try removing the second one with an empty content attribute which is most likely your problem since it is coming after the first meta tag, essentially overriding it: <meta name="viewport" id="sv-meta" content>

Comment: Thanks for your help blueice, truly appreciate it!  

I'm not able to find the second viewport, or meta tag. How where you able to view that? What simulator where you using? I think the WP theme must be auto generating it. I can not see it within view source of the page itself, and it's definitly not in my header.php.

Comment: Np hopefully you can track down how that second viewport is being introduced. I was using the IOS simulator and viewing your web page source through the safari remote debug tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact an extra meta tag. Here it is and here's its id. `<meta name="viewport" id="sv-meta" content="">`

It doesn't show up on desktops, so it's probably being generated by this script `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grupoevents.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-simpleviewer/svcore/js/simpleviewer.js?ver=2.3.2.1"></script>`. You should look into the settings for that plugin, but if you can't find any, then you might be able to use this javascript at the end of your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var svMeta = document.getElementById('sv-meta');
  if(svMeta){ svMeta.parentElement.removeChild(svMeta) }
</script>
```